# Position an image next to a div (chat bubble)

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image of a user next to a "chat bubble" but the image is being displayed after the bubble.

How can i position the image before the chat bubble and stick to the div?

My code is here: http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/fFxtl

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the code on this page. It helps to see the code and it is best to ensure the content on the link doesn't change. A fiddle is always good though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want to achieve

http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/afyuj

```
.bubble2{
 float:left 

}

.bubble
{
text-align:left;
color:black;
float:left;
position: relative;
background: gray;
border-left: 2px solid #e67e22;
margin-bottom:3%;
margin-left:0;
padding:5px;
}

.bubble h4 {text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;font-variant:small-caps;clear:both;margin-bottom:3px;padding:0;margin-top:-5px;color:#2ecc71;}
.bubble span {font-size:17px;line-height:1px;font-family: TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;}
```

Comment: That worked but it broke my last problem, you removed CLEAR:BOTH on bubble class! That means when i add multiple bubble classes, they are not correctly listing under each other instead next to each other. Please help - http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/HcpLJ

Comment: can you give me a screenshot if what is your final design or what you want to achieve as from your text hard to understand

Comment: but you can't start with img tag, always recommended to out inside a containers. see this with lesser code and in css i have use short code http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/EdaCn

Comment: http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/rgHld - I added a "name tag" under the image, but it messed up the chat bubble. Any solution San? Thanks!

Comment: here you go http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/suEeA. always imagine the css model before you start working